# How to filter product collection using ratings?

Tags: magento

I want to filter the product collection using "Ratings". As it is not an attribute of products how can i do that?

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
             ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc');
```

I want to do Ratings filtering for the above collection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found a [solution](http://www.netismine.com/magento/sort-product-list-by-rating) here. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: The solution that you have provided is sort product list using ratings. But i need product filtering.